# Split a string, at every nth position, with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I have the following string:

```
foofaafoofaafoofaafoofaafoofaa
```

An array with 10 rows (if I split by every 3rd character, that is), which looks something like this, if I were to instantiate it:

```
var fooarray = new Array ('foo', 'faa', 'foo', 'faa', 'foo', 'faa', 'foo', 'faa', 'foo', 'faa');
```

So I want a function, either built-in or custom-made, which can help me split up a string by every nth character.

Comment: There's an answer here that does just that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017671/how-do-you-split-a-string-at-certain-character-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try the below code:

```js
var foo = "foofaafoofaafoofaafoofaafoofaa";
console.log( foo.match(/.{1,3}/g) );
```

For nth position:

```
foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,' + n + '}', 'g'));
```

Comment: @xdazz But the OP said every nth position; your regex is fixed at 3.  Generalize it for an upvote. :)

Comment: Can you split it using regex but from right to left?

Comment: @vsync: I don't know if that's possible in the *general* case, but maybe you could just reverse the input string, do the matches, then reverse the output?

Comment: bravo my friend that is a very nice use of regex

Answer (score 12):

```js
var s = "foofaafoofaafoofaafoofaafoofaa";
var a = [];
var i = 3;

do{ a.push(s.substring(0, i)) } 
while( (s = s.substring(i, s.length)) != "" );

console.log( a )
```

Prints:

```
foo,faa,foo,faa,foo,faa,foo,faa,foo,faa
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9RXTW/

Answer (score 7):

As I was writing this, @xdazz came up with the wonderfully simple regex solution.

But as you have asked (on the comments to that answer) for a non-regex solution, I will submit this anyway...

```js
function splitNChars(txt, num) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i += num) {
    result.push(txt.substr(i, num));
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(splitNChars("foofaafoofaafoofaafoofaafoofaa",3));
```

Comment: Also `array` doesnt make a good variable name. Even thought Javascript  is case sensitive it might be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this:

```
var input = "foofaafoofaafoofaafoofaafoofaa";

var result = [];
while (input.length) {
    result.push(input.substr(0, 3));
    input = input.substr(3);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/yAZJ2/

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Walter has pointed out, this solution from [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017671/how-do-you-split-a-string-at-certain-character-numbers-in-javascript) works perfectly:

```
function splitStringAtInterval (string, interval) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0; i<string.length; i+=interval)
    result.push(string.substring (i, i+interval));
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function followed by an example using it. The example test outputs: `["abc","def","ghi","j"]`

```
function splitEvery(str, n)
{
    var arr = new Array;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += n)
    {
        arr.push(str.substr(i, n));
    }
    return arr;
}

var result = splitEvery('abcdefghij', 3);
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```