# How to separate variables in to arrays of 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dna-sequence

So What this is supposed to do, minus the mouseenter/mouseleave functions, is to take user input, divide it in to an array with 3 letters in each array placement (ex. User input abcdef... will turn in to abc, def,...). I read a different post on stack overflow, ([How do you split a string at certain character numbers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4017671)). However, I can't quite get this to function in my following code.

Here is my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_translate').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#button_translate').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('#button_translate').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#button_translate').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
    });
    $('#button_clear').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#button_clear').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('#button_clear').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#button_clear').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
    });
    $('#button_translate').click(function() {
        var dna = $('input[name=dna]').val();
        var dna = dna.toUpperCase();
        function allBases(text) {  
            var bases = /^[ACGT]+$/;  
            if(text.match(bases)) {  

                var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(dna), output = [];
                while (arr.length) output.push(arr.splice(0, 3).join('');
                document.write(arr + " is a DNA sequence.");

            }
            else
            {  
                document.write(dna + " is not a real DNA sequence.");
            }  
        }

        allBases(dna);

    });
});
```

Comment: What about spaces? If a user enters 'i am a great person', what would the arrays be?

Comment: This looks correct.  What fails about it?  Did you mean to use the output?  (You don't seem to be currently)

Comment: You are missing a `)` .. check my answer. it should work fine.

Comment: look here: http://jsfiddle.net/lxgreen/8DF7T/

Comment: Sorry for the inactivity. It will only accept a string with the characters a, c, t, or g. No need to worry about sentences. Yes, I couldn't get any output to verify it was working. The Accepted Answer took car of the question with one simple line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this post might help:

[Split string into array of equal length strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359905/split-string-into-array-of-equal-length-strings)

Applying it to your code, you could replace:

```
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(dna), output = [];
    while (arr.length) output.push(arr.splice(0, 3).join('');
```

with:

```
    var arr = text.match(/.{1,3}/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```
while (arr.length) output.push(arr.splice(0, 3).join('');
```

to this

```
while (arr.length) output.push(arr.splice(0, 3).join(''));
```

Notice the difference ? **Missing `)` at the end !!**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need looping, you could use a regular expression. If I assume you want to treat all characters equally (spaces, number, punctuation) then:

```
var userString = 'I am a terrible swimmer';
var resultArray = userString.match(/[\s\S]{1,3}/g);
```

**\s\S** = anything.
**{1,3}** = between 1 and three charaters. This will give you groups of three characters, and whatever is left over at the end (for if your string has, say, four characters in it).